# Apply a function to Pandas dataframe row by row (axis = 0) to create four new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been playing around with this but I can't even get the simplest case to work so I'm going to ask for assistance.

I have a large dataframe and I'm trying to add four new columns to it. The values for each column is dependent on the data in the row as per the if statements below.

Here is what I'd sketched out so far:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Signal': [0,1,1,0],
   'Win': [False,True,False,False],
   'Odds': [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4],
   'Helper': [True,False,False,False],
   'before': ['','','',''],
   'stake':['','','',''],
   'result':['','','',''],
   'after':['','','','']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

def function(df, start, stake_size):
   '''
   takes in three arguments: a dataframe, a start number as int and 
   stake_size as int
   the function fills up before, stake, result, after columns row by row 
   using the IF statements below
   '''
   #if df['Helper']:
   #    df['before'] = start
   #else:
   #    df['before'] = df['after'].shift(1)

   df['before'] = start #This is so I can replicate the example

   if df['Signal'] == 0:
       df['stake'] = 0
       df['result'] = 0
   elif df['Signal'] == 1:
       df['stake'] = df['before'] * (stake_size/100)

   if (df['Signal'] == 1 & df['Win'] == True):
       df['result'] = (df['stake'] * df['odds']) - df['stake']
   else:
       df['result'] = df['stake'] * -1

   df['after'] = df['before'] + df['result']

   return df

df.apply(function, args=(100,5), axis=1)
```

Suffice to say, this doesn't get me anywhere.

I'm used to using `.apply(function, axis=1)` to create columns but that won't work in this case as in order to calculate before, I need to calculate after in the same row. Ie. each row needs to be filled sequentially. That's why I'd tried to approach this as a function that takes in the row and calculates the values for the four new columns.

I'd appreciate any assistance or similar examples to get unstuck here. Thanks.

**EDIT:** I've taken the advice from HakunaMaData and added the Helper column to the df to ensure I apply the first if statement as I intended. I had initially thought `.shift` was going to work here but it won't because I can't shift the whole dataframe when applying along a row, right?

Is there another way I can approach this?

The intended output I'm looking for is:

```
answer = {'Signal': [0,1,1,0],
          'Win': [False,True,False,False],
          'Odds': [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4],
          'Helper': [True,False,False,False],
          'before': [100,100,101,94.95],
          'stake':[0,5,5,0],
          'result':[0,1,-5,0],
          'after':[100,101,95.95,95.95]
          }
```

Comment: Can the mods change the title of this post? I was fairly confused when I first posted this and now it doesn't make sense. Needs to be something more like: Tracking and using the value of the previous row when using .apply to fill new columns in a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

Before, Stake, After, Result etc. should be numeric types and not strings. So change them - like so:

```
d = {'Signal': [0,1,1,0],
   'Win': [False,True,False,False],
   'Odds': [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4],
   'before': [0]*4,
   'stake':[0]*4,
   'result':[0]*4,
   'after':[0]*4
}
```

Now the rest of the code generally works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

def function(df, start, stake_size):

   '''
   takes in three arguments: a dataframe, a start number as int and 
   stake_size as int
   the function fills up before, stake, result, after columns row by row 
   using the IF statements below
   '''

   global after #Create a global variable to track the value in the previous row

   if df.name == 0: 
       df['before'] = start
   else: 
        df['before'] = after 

   if df['Signal'] == 0:
       df['stake'] = 0
       df['result'] = 0
   elif df['Signal'] == 1:
       df['stake'] = df['before'] * (stake_size/100)

   if (df['Signal'] == 1 & df['Win'] == True):
       df['result'] = (df['stake'] * df['odds']) - df['stake']
   else:
       df['result'] = df['stake'] * -1

   df['after'] = df['before'] + df['result']

   after = df['after'] #assign the value to the global variable at the end

   return df
```

Finally, Use the row axis and not the column axis:

```
df.apply(function, args=(100,5), axis=1)
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @HakunaMaData this is a big step forward. I'm able to replicate this result and make a couple of small changes to other errors that I've edited above. However, I intended the ['before'] column to behave differently. In the result it should be: 100, 100, 101, 94.95. Are you also able to provide any pointers on that?

Comment: You could use a global variable to track the value of after from the previous row. Also.. I can't get to 94.95.. I think it should be 95.95 instead based on the data you have supplied.

Answer (score 1):

first you need to change your function, you will apply row by row using :
`df.apply(lambda x: function(x,100,5), axis=1)`

Then your function's signature will be :

```
def function(row,start,stake_size):
    # Your conditions...
    return row
```

Caution ! In this case, you're not manipulating a dataframe with `apply()` but a row so you'll have to adapt your code in the function.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks @Clem. I've also tried this approach and I can produce the same output as the other reply but that isn't exactly what I'm after. I'm still struggling with how to set the value of column ['before'] in the current row based on the value in a ['after'] column in the row above.